# I kept getting an error that says unknown column film_category.category_id in on clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've tried doing like this:

```
select film.title,category.name,category.category_id
from film
inner join film_actor on film.film_id= film_actor.film_id
inner join category on
film_category.category_id=category.category_id;
```

then I execute it I am getting the error saying

> unknown column `film_category.category_id` in on clause

.

Comment: You are not joining "film_category"  table in your query

Comment: It is joining by film_category table but I don't understand if which query  part is not joining?

Comment: You are using category_id field in film_category table to join with category table... but there is no such table. In your query you are using only 3 tables(film, film_actor and category ).

Answer (score 0):

The query in the question joins `film` with `film_actor` with `category`, so there is not a table called `film_category` in this query, which is what the error is saying.

Since you genuinely have one table called `category` and a different one called `film_category` then you need to join that other table into the query, like this:

```
select film.title,category.name,category.category_id
from film
inner join film_actor
    on film.film_id= film_actor.film_id
inner join film_category
    on film.film_id=film_category.film_id
inner join category
    on category.category_id=film_category.category_id;
```

This should solve the error.

Comment: It isn't a typo at all. Here's the table for film_category which contains category_id (pk/fk),filmid(pk/fk), table for film contains filmid(pk) title, category table contains category_id(pk),name and film_actor table contains film_id(pk,fk),category_id(pk,fk).